# How to call overridePendingTransition() when Activity is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, transition

I've been tweaking a lot with android design and capability of Android to use the maximum potential of an Android framework, I have come across transition, and my question is how to define Activity's Destroyed's animation ?. Say I am starting an activity using intent like so :

```
    Intent intent_info = new Intent(ComponentsPage.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_info);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.no_change);
```

That snippet basically opens up SecondActivity with Slide Up transition. Now i am in second activity and second activity say doesn't have any button but i want whenever Second Activity is closing (Destroyed) it close with slide down animation.

I've tried adding

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_change,R.anim.slide_down);
```

Inside onDestroy() and onStop(), but still no luck, i guess the activity is already closed when those methods are called.

Comment: override finish method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you try to finish the second activity try to override the finish method inside your SecondActivity as follows:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_change, R.anim.slide_down);
}
```

Comment: i see, well i've never thought of that, your answer a door to whole another dimension for me. thanks!

Comment: @StringForever i've tried it in java 8 and it worked. Why did you say it wont work ?

Comment: Okay maybe I messed something up in eclispe

Comment: @Squareroot no disrespect, but can you delete your comment about this not working in java8+?  it causes unnecessary confusion.